# Filter records from Couchbase with where clause using N1QL Query in Java

Tags: java, api, couchbase

I need to have a where clause in my query to filter out records which is less than the week passed as a parameter.

Java Code(N1QL Query):

```
statement = select("distinct Week, Season")                     
.from(i(bucketName.toString())).where((x("meta().id").like(s("TescoWeek%"))))
                .orderBy(Sort.asc("Week"));
        return couchBaseRepository.getQueryResultAsString(cluster, bucketName, statement);
```

I want to get only the records which are greater than "201526" from "Week" field.

Couchbase Doc sample is:

```
{
  "id": "SS16-201525",
  "type": "TescoWeeks",
  "Season": "SS16",
  "Week": "201525"
}
```

Thanks,
IRK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below query and got my expected result.

```
statement = select("distinct id, Season, Week") 
.from(i(bucketName.toString())).where(x("Season").eq(s(seasonId)).and(x("meta().id").like(s("TescoWeek%"))
                .and(x("Week").gte(s(startWeek)))))
                .orderBy(Sort.asc("Week")); 
        System.out.println(statement.toString());
        return couchBaseRepository.getQueryResultAsString(cluster, bucketName, statement);
```